# Comparing two similar XML data with unordered elements/attributes in Java

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, junit, xmlunit

I'm looking for an API which compares two XML data. I've tried XMLUnit 2 but couldn't find a way to make it work properly with my example. Could you give me an example which works for my need?

My first XML data `xml1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemap.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>a1/</loc>
        <lastmod>a2</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>b1</loc>
        <lastmod>b2</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>c1</loc>
        <lastmod>c2</lastmod>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

My second XML data `xml2`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemap.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url><lastmod>b2</lastmod><loc>b1</loc></url>
    <url>
        <lastmod>c2</lastmod>
        <loc>c1</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>a1/</loc>
        <lastmod>a2</lastmod>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Notice:

- Same size (here 3 children)
- `urlset`'s child nodes (`url`) may not be ordered
- `url`'s elements (`loc` and `lastmod`) may not be ordered
- White spaces are ignored

Looking for an API which returns `true` like:

```
XMLUtils.isSimilar(xml1, xml2);
```

My unsuccessful attempts with XMLUnit 2 (tried with multiple "NodeMatcher"):

```
// Attempt with XmlAssert.assertThat:
XmlAssert.assertThat(xml1)
    .and(xml2)
    .ignoreChildNodesOrder()
    .ignoreWhitespace()
    .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .areSimilar();

// Attempt with Diff
Diff myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(xml1)
    .withTest(xml2)
    .ignoreWhitespace()
    .checkForSimilar()
    .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
     .build();
myDiff.getDifferences();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try as below

```
public class XMLUtils {
    private static DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory;
    private static DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
    private static TransformerFactory transformerFactory;
    private static Transformer transformer;
    private static Document emptyDoc;

    public XMLUtils() {
    }

    public XMLCompareResult compare(File expectedFile, File actualFile, boolean ignoreWhiteSpace) throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException, IOException {
        FileInputStream expInpStream = new FileInputStream(expectedFile);
        FileInputStream actualInpStream = new FileInputStream(actualFile);
        Diff myDiff = null;
        if (ignoreWhiteSpace) {
            myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(expInpStream).withTest(actualInpStream).checkForSimilar().ignoreWhitespace().withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(new ElementSelector[]{ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes})).build();
        } else {
            myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(expInpStream).withTest(actualInpStream).checkForSimilar().withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(new ElementSelector[]{ElementSelectors.byNameAndAllAttributes})).build();
        }

        XMLResultUtil xmlr = new XMLResultUtil();
        XMLCompareResult xs = xmlr.prepareXMLCompareResult(myDiff.getDifferences());
        return xs;
    }  

    static {
        try {
            documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            emptyDoc = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException var1) {
            var1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException var2) {
            var2.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I copying here a method we are using in my project.

Could you try it and let me know if you are facing any issue. I can try by myself again.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem likely is "what are the matching `url` elements?". I can only guess and assume for you the `url`s with the same text inside the `loc` child are the matching elements - and this is what you need to tell XMLUnit.

Your example is very common but still something that cannot be guessed (apart fom brute-forcing all possible permutations and picking the one with the least differences). It is the running example of https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes you only need to replace `tr` with `uri` and `th` with `loc`.

To make things concrete. When comparing the `url` elements you want XMLUnit to look at the respective `loc` children and compare their nested text. In all other cases you are happy with selecting among sibling elements by their name (there is only one `urlset` and each pair of `loc` and `lastmod` siblings is uniquely decided by their tag names).

The translates to a conditional `ElementSelector`

```
ElementSelectors.conditionalBuilder()
    .whenElementIsNamed("url").thenUse(ElementSelectors
        .byXPath("./loc", ElementSelectors.byNameAndText))
    .elseUse(ElementSelectors.byName)
    .build();
```

With that you should be able to get down to a "similar" result where the only differences found are child order differences.