# How to compare 2 XML-s for similarity?

Tags: java, xml, testing

I have a XML in format

```
<Response>
    <Result>
       <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
       <Message>Some message 1</Message>
    </Result>
    <Result>
       <Status>FAIL</Status>
       <Message>Some message 2</Message>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

And i need to compare it to

```
<Response>
    <Result>
       <Status>FAIL</Status>
       <Message>Some message 2</Message>
    </Result>
    <Result>
       <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
       <Message>Some message 1</Message>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

They are similar, but  not identical. I tried using XMLunit to compare these, but i keep getting errors that thye are not similar

My code:

```
assertThat(result, isSimilarTo(control).withNodeMatchers(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementsSelector.byName)))
```

This seems to ignote the order of elements within the `<Result>` but does not ignore the order of `<Result>` elements themselves.

How can i achieve the similarity check?

Comment: Robin La Fontaine gave a paper on this topic last week at Balisage 2021: see https://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol26/html/LaFontaine01/BalisageVol26-LaFontaine01.html Perhaps his company, DeltaXML, has something to offer. Document comparison is a complex topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a well defined type for Response in your code, then you can implement your similarity check with scoring. For example:
First, deserialize the XMLs in Response objects. If this is successful, define score=0. Then, compare the number of Results and add the difference to the score. Then, for each Result in the first object, find the one in the second object which is most similar - use an implementation of the Damerau–Levenshtein algorithm to compare each field, e.g. Status and Message and add the smallest distance sum (dist(status1, status2) + dist(message1, message2)) to the score. Or you can use this algorithm only for the Message and not the Status, if this makes more sense. At the end - the lower score means more similar. You could test and define your pivot, above which the objects are considered not similar.

Comment: While it might work... it might be too much work, as the system needs to be fast. What i found about XMLUtil that i can define a conditional ElementSelector. Basically If it meet element Response, it then checks the Message element by name and text. Otherwise it will use just name. This works just fine.

Comment: Yes, it is slow. On the other hand I would imagine that everything comparing XMLs is slow because of the unordered nature of the entities. I'll take a look at XMLUtil as I'm interested in a similar solution myself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363758/comparing-two-similar-xml-data-with-unordered-elements-attributes-in-java Stefans answer here is what helped me